# Render results of Nodejs Mongoose in Swig template

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, swig

I'm using Express 3.x
This is code in my controller:

```
Post.find({}, function(error, docs) {
   res.render('posts/index', {
        title: 'List of Posts',
        posts: docs,
      })
});
```

And in my swig template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
 {{post.message}}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, no post's message render.

Please help me!

Comment: 1. Ensure you have posts; 2. Ensure that there's no `error`.